# What is this flickering menu bar icon?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Can anyone identify this menu bar icon?

[image]

Every minute or so, it quickly appears and disappears in my menu bar, just for a few seconds.

Comment: Based on the sparsity of the information in your question, it is just pure luck someone will answer it. Did you try clicking on it? did you try removing it from the menu bar ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do either, because it appears and disappears too quickly. I was only able to see it by recording a movie of the screen -- before that I just saw some flickering.

Comment: It looks like the screen sharing icon, from iChat.

Comment: Kent -- I think you're right. It's the icon that appears when someone else is sharing your screen. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the screen sharing icon, from iChat; when someone is sharing your screen.